# login and "/home" redirect me to "/email/verify" LARAVEL 5.8

Tags: php, laravel-5

I'm new in LARAVEL so please don't kill me for my question. I'm now tring to make an email verification. I searched alot but can't find a good answer for my case.

and here is my homeController

```
 <?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class HomeController extends Controller
{
/**
 * Create a new controller instance.
 *
 * @return void
 */

public function __construct()
{


$this->middleware('auth');
$this->middleware('verified');

$this->middleware('auth', ['except' => ['index', 'show']]);


    // $this->middleware(['auth','verified']);
 //  $this->middleware(['auth']);
}

/**
 * Show the application dashboard.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Support\Renderable
 */
public function index()
{
    return view('home');
}
}
```

The email verification works very well and sends me an email.

**My problem is after login the website should take the user to home page but It takes the user to "/email/verify" page.**

**Even if I tried to write /home in the url it redirects to "/email/verify"**

here is my web.php file

```
Auth::routes(['verify' => true]);

Route::get('profile', function () {
// Only verified users may enter...
})->middleware('verified');
Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
//Admin Role route
 Route::get('/admin', 'AdminController@index');
```

**I don't know what's the wrong or missing with my code, So please can AnyOne help me ?? 
I'm Working on localhost BTW**

here is screen shot for the email verification page. 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ePHkQ.png)

Comment: it's probably because the verification link in emails does not work , look into DB and check `verified_at` field in `users` table. if its null then user is not verified!

Comment: i looked in the database and found it null but do you think that because i'm working on localhost and it will work when i'm working online ??

Comment: no I dont think so. show me the verification link in the email

Comment: i don't understand  would you please explain more ??

Comment: i'm using trapmail for testing verificaton mails

Comment: copy the verificatin link from your trap mail and paste it here! I want to see whats the url look like

Comment: https://mailtrap.io/inboxes/651681/messages/1330562520

Answer (score 1):

Try to remove `$this->middleware('verified');` in your homeController. I guess everthing will work as expected.

Comment: it will work but will be no verification email any more for register too

Comment: check the code again i added the home controller code

Comment: Same issue... Any solution?